# Open VIM with Java application

Tags: java, vim

I need my Java console application to do the following:

1. Open VIM
2. < the user input multiple lines of words and :wq >
3. My application should then be able to get the vim input and print it in the terminal.

So far I'm stuck at 1.. It seems impossible to get Java to open VIM!

Here is some non functional code I have been fiddling with:

[call system text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833828/call-system-text-editor)

http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java

Advice much appreciated

EDIT

Ok so the following will open VIM but backgrounded. Any way around this?

```
String[] command = {"/usr/bin/vim", "test.txt"};
Process vimProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
vimProcess.waitFor();
```

Comment: What have you tried? I believe running a "/usr/bin/vim" as cmd should work for 1

Comment: I am trying to open a vi Editor, if if use check in windows & call Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad C:\\test.txt"); I am able to achieve it. But when I try the same for Linux , Runtime.getRuntime().exec("vi /tmp/test.txt"); I feel it opens as a background rather then active terminal. Any hint for same.

Comment: It's not opening in the background, you just haven't redirected or captured stdin/stdout so its output is going nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. run vim from java (notice that this will work on gnome, if you use KDE use "konsole"):

   `Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnome-terminal -e 'vim /tmp/tmpfile'");`
2. wait the user will finish and exit:

   `int exitVal = pr.waitFor();     //check for the right exitVal`
3. read the input and write to the terminal:

   `System.out.println(FileUtils.raedFileToString(new File("/tmp/tmpfile")));`

Comment: The following line will not open VIM:
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/vim /tmp/tmpfile");
If I run /usr/bin/vim directly in the term it opens

Comment: I run the jar and nothing happens:

jn@UL80Vt:~/NetBeansProjects/Test/dist$ java -jar Test.jar 
jn@UL80Vt:~/NetBeansProjects/Test/dist$

Comment: it's because the vim is starting in the background and you can't see it. why are you want to open vim exactly?

Comment: Any way around this? I want to feed my application with multiple lines of input in the term without any gui. I would love to be able to do the actual editing in vim

Comment: You are right I can find the backgrounded vim process hmm, would I then need to background my jar to show vim and then revert or something?